# animation gives zero division

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to perfomr an animation for a given function.

My problem right now is that it gives me a division by zero but I can't see how this is happening.

I have put some print statements and they are ok.

I am not sure how the FuncAnimation works , because if I omit this call and just run "animate(n) " instead , then I have no errors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


R = 1
b = 0.02
m0 = 0.02
n = np.linspace( 1,0.01 ,10)
r = np.linspace( 0,R ,10 )

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
line, = axes.plot([], [], lw=2)


def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(n):
    u_r = ( ( b / 2 * m0 ) ** (1/n) ) * ( n/(n+1) ) * ( R**(1+1/n ) - r**(1+1/n) )
    print()
    print( "1/n = {0} , n/n+1= {1} ,1+1/n = {2}".format( 1/n, n/(n+1),1+(1/n)))
    print()
    print(u_r)
    line.set_data(r, u_r[0]*u_r)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                              frames=len(n),blit=False)

plt.show()
```

The error is in the line :

```
u_r = ( ( b / 2 * m0 ) ** (1/n) ) * ( n/(n+1) ) * ( R**(1+1/n ) - r**(1+1/n) )
```

Comment: BTW You use `animate` as a parameter for `FuncAnimation` and have a function with the same name.

Comment: You have a module-level variable `n`, but that variable is hidden within the scope of the `animate` function, because the *argument* to `animate` is also called `n`.  That argument will be an integer, ranging from 0 to `len(n)-1`.  See my answer.

Comment: what is your animation supposed to do? Do you want to calculate u_r for each value of n? Or something else?

Comment: @ Diziet Asahi:Yes , I want to see how u_r varies for each value of n.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an integer as the `frames` argument of `FuncAnimation`, the first argument passed to your callback (`animate`, in this case) will be an integer that ranges from 0 to one less than the integer given as `frames`.  So the first call to `animate(n)` has `n = 0`, which results in a division by 0 at the indicated line.

A possible fix is to change `frames=len(n)` to `frames=n`.

Comment: :So , I changed to frames = n  , I have no division by zero error but I have no animation also. ( the formula works fine ,is tested )